# Hibernate JPA CriteriaQuery with count and where predicate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am trying to replicate the results of this query in JPA/Hibernate with a CriteriaQuery.

```
select count(*) from tbl_survey where CREATED_DATE > to_date('2020-04-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

The daysBack value is passed in as a parameter.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, daysBack);
    Date daysAgo = cal.getTime();
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<Survey> root = cq.from(Survey.class);
        Path<Date> dateCreated = root.<Date>get("createdDate");
        Predicate datePredicate = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(dateCreated, daysAgo);
        cq.where(datePredicate);
        cq.select(cb.count(cq.from(Survey.class)));

        long count = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
        JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject();
        resultJson.put(SURVEY_COUNT, count);

        logger.info("Count for Survey table is: {}", count);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resultJson.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        return new ResponseEntity(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

The log output is: 
    Count for Survey table is: 36

However there are only 6 rows in the table which suggests to me some sort of self-join or cross product is being generated to create the output of 36. What should I be doing differently to get the correct count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self joining occurs for this line where you use new root

```
cq.select(cb.count(cq.from(Survey.class)));
```

root used for where condition and count query is different that caused self joining. Use same root for count query also

```
cq.select(cb.count(root));
```